# Finding count of unique values of current month not present in the last 4 months

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I want to count the unique IDs for a particular month which has not registered for the past 4 months. Currently, I am using this query which does not take into consideration certain sub cases and is highly inefficient for a large database -

```
select month(dd/mm/yyyy), (count(distinct ID) - sum(l)) 
from
(select x.ID, x.dd/mm/yyyy, y.ID as ID2, y.dd/mm/yyyy as Date2, (case when x.ID = y.ID then 1 else 0 end as l) from table1 x
left join table1 y 
on y.dd/mm/yyyy between dateadd(month,-4, x.dd/mm/yyyy) and dateadd(month,-1, x.dd/mm/yyyy))
group by month(dd/mm/yyyy) 
order by month(dd/mm/yyyy);

   (dd/mm/yyyy) ID  
    01/01/2018  A  
    01/02/2018  B  
    02/02/2018  C  
    01/03/2018  A    
    02/03/2018  D  
    01/04/2018  D  
    02/04/2018  E        
    01/05/2018  E         
    02/05/2018  A    
    01/05/2018  F        
    01/05/2018  G
```

Expected Result -

```
Month Count
1      1    --(A)
2      2    --(B,C)
3      1    --(D)
4      1    --(E)
5      2    --(F,G)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate by month and then use `lag()` to see where the previous value is:

```
select yyyymm,
       sum(case when prev_yyyymm is null or
                     prev_yyyymm < dateadd(month, -3, yyyymm)
                then 1 else 0
           end) as cnt
from (select t.id, v.yyyymm,
             count(*) as cnt,  -- not needed but perhaps fun to have
             lag(v.yyyymm) over (partition by t.id order by v.yyyymm) as prev_yyyymm
      from t cross apply
           (values (datefromparts(year(date_filled), month(date_filled), 1)
           ) v(yyyymm)
     ) t
group by yyyymm
order by yyyymm;
```